# Trying to understand Laravel's Passport need for 5 tables in DB and why not in .env

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am building a REST API, no views, just routing for a front written in Angular.
For auth purposes, I need to create tokens, send them in the payload and verify them.

My question is why do I need to have 5 tables for this, would it be possible to store the secret on the ENV and just operate without calling the DB each time? I've been googling for answers on this without avail, hope to get clarity here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You require these tables. `oauth_clients` table stores your `client_id` and `client_secret`.

There are different type of `clients` available, in your case its better to use **password client** (where `password_client` set to `1` in `auth_clients table`).

```
{
 "username": "your-laravel-username",
 "password": "your-laravel-password",
 "client_id": id-from-oauth-clients-table,
 "client_secret": secret-from-oauth-cleints-table,
 "grant_type": "password", //this is to use password client, search for password_client - 1 in oauth_client table
 "scope": "conference"
```

}

This `client_id` and `client_secret` you can use in the login request to get the `bearer token`. This `bearer token` you can use to get the access to all the apis.

Once you have the `bearer token` ready you can use it for further request, now need to use the login api for each request.

Comment: You didn't mention the word `env` even once, did you understand my question?

Comment: I hope you want to store the client_secret in .env variable, right?

Comment: Password Grant Tokens aren't [recommended](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#password-grant-tokens).